# Download Network Boot Image

Tags: linux, networking, boot

If an OS is booted from the network, is there a way I can "download" this image so I can boot from it on another computer without network access?

Comment: PXE uses tftp, so yes, you can "download" it. But how are you planning to tell the computer without network access to boot from it?

Comment: If I can download the image on computer A and get it on a drive, I can boot from it on B, or not? And how can I download the image? tftp cannot list files so I have no idea of the filename ...

Comment: AFAIK, network images are different from images you use to boot from USB sticks or CDs, so you may have to modify the image, but I may be wrong. IIRC, the filename should be given back by the DHCP server in the DHCP response, so snoop a request/response, or fake one for the host you want to run it on. Note that the filename can be different depending on the information in the DHCP request (because different machines can boot from the same server).